# Mix of change/changes

Tags: sentence-construction

I read a sentence in a newspaper

[The allocation appears to be a mix of bold **change** in the top four of the Cabinet Committee on Security (CCS) with a status quo in the rest.](https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/narendra-modi-cabinet-ministers-and-portfolios/article27375561.ece)

I think here **changes** should be used.

Answer (score -1):

No, the singular is correct here, since it refers to the Cabinet Committee as a whole, not to the individual members.